# Async - wait for two async tasks to finish

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous

I have two function calls that are run in my code, and when both are done, the function ProcessFiles is run. Like this:

```
  byte[] file1 = doSomething();
  byte[] file2 = doSomethingElse();

  ProcessFiles(file1, file2);
```

These two functioncalls `DoSomething` and `DoSomethingElse` are completely seperate, and I was thinking of running these in a different thread so they are run simultaneously.
However, I need to process the results (file1 and file2) when both are done.

I guess async await (or its VB.NET equivalent) is the way to go here, but for the life of me, I can't find any good examples that showcase this. Maybe I'm using the wrong search queries, but so far I haven't been able to get a good example. Can anyone point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 5):

Yes, you can do this easily with async/await. For example:

```
// If you don't have async equivalents, you could use Task.Run
// to start the synchronous operations in separate tasks.
// An alternative would be to use Parallel.Invoke
Task<byte[]> task1 = DoSomethingAsync();
Task<byte[]> task2 = DoSomethingElseAsync();

byte[] file1 = await task1;
byte[] file2 = await task2;
ProcessFiles(file1, file2);
```

The important thing is that you don't await either task until you've *started* both of them.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Am I right in assuming that the main thread will block at the line "byte[] file1 = await task1" ? And that if task2 is done first, this won't matter (meaning the result is not lost)

Comment: @StevenLemmens: Yes on both counts. If `task2` completes first, that just means that as soon as `task1` completes, the `await task2` will execute very quickly (without even scheduling a continuation).

Answer (score 5):

> I was thinking of running these in a different thread... I guess async await

Note that `async`/`await` does not imply any particular kind of threading. Async/await deals with asynchronous code, not parallel code. For more information, see my [`async` intro](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html).

However, you can use `Task.Run` to execute code on a thread pool thread, and then you can use `Task.WhenAll` to (asynchronously) wait for them both to complete:

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => doSomething());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => doSomethingElse());

var results = await Task.WhenAll(task1, task2);
ProcessFiles(results[0], results[1]);
```

Alternatively, since your code is already synchronous, you can use `WaitAll`. Note that your error handling is different with parallel code (you need to be prepared for `AggregateException`):

```
var task1 = Task.Run(() => doSomething());
var task2 = Task.Run(() => doSomethingElse());

Task.WaitAll(task1, task2);
ProcessFiles(task1.Result, task2.Result);
```

Comment: Thanks for the code examples and the extra explanation. Great read on your blog as well about async/await. Now for one extra question: something I hadn't considered before. My doSomething() method actually uses some data about the current user. is there a way of passing the current context automatically to the task that's being run? I'm using your second example right now.

Comment: @StevenLemmens: I believe you'd have to set the thread's principal specifically from the worker thread. AFAIK there's no easier way to flow it.